# Creating pages for individual products in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a "Category", "Subcategory" and "Product" model. Rather than having a view for each category, subcategory and product I want to href to templates that will be filled with the righ models.

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="category")
    category_description = models.TextField()
    category_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, default=1)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_title 


class Subcategory(models.Model):
    subcategory_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subcategory_image = models.ImageField()
    subcategory_category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, default=1, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Subcategories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subcategory_title


class Product(models.Model):
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product_image = models.ImageField()
    product_base_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    product_addons = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    product_description = models.TextField()
    product_date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    product_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, default=1)
    product_subcategory = models.ForeignKey(
    Subcategory, default=1, verbose_name="Subcategories", on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    product_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

### To list all products with a link to a specific product

Here is a sample `view`, `url` & `template` for Product model. Please replace `myapp` with you app's name.

Define a view:

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Product

class ProductList(ListView):
    model = Product

def productdetail(request,id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id = id)
    return render(request, 'myapp/product.html', {'product': product})
```

Finally hook that view into your urls:

```
# urls.py
from django.urls import path
from myapp.views import ProductList, productdetail

urlpatterns = [
    path('products/', ProductList.as_view()),
    path('products/<int:pk>/', productdetail, name='productdetail'),
]
```

create a template to list products at: `/path/to/project/myapp/templates/myapp/products_list.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Products</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for product in object_list %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'productdetail' product.id %}">{{ product.product_title }} </a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

create a template to show a specific product: `/path/to/project/myapp/templates/myapp/product.html`::

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Product</h2>
    {{product.product_title}}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I think I worded my question badly. I don't know how to click on a product and have it load a template with attributes from a specific product

Comment: @GTA.sprx i updated my answer for a specific product tooo

Comment: Where do you get `product-detail` from? I get `Reverse for 'product-detail' not found. 'product-detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: fixed a bug in the answer. have you added `path('products/<int:pk>/', productdetail, name='product-detail'),` in root `urls.py`?

Comment: I managed to get it working by doing `path('products/<int:pk>/', product_detail, name='product-detail'),` in my root urls.py and changing `id` to `pk` in my view. Now I just need to make my url use slugs such as `mysite.com/t-shirts/blue-shirt` and creating product category pages filled with products of the corresponding foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

```
    product_created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I have the answer, just use `DateTimeField()`

Answer (score 0):

You used:

```py
product = Product.objects.get(id = id)
```

change it to :

```py
product = Product.objects.get(id = pk)
```